# About zero voltage switching boost converter designing

Tags: boost, converter, zvs

I am developing zero voltage switching in a boost converter for input 48 V and current is 20 Ah. Also:

- output power is 60 W,
- output voltage is 200 V,
- output maximum current is 0.35 A.

What is switching frequency for this circuit? How to decide all of the parameters for the given circuit?

Comment: Current is 20Ah? What do you mean? Ah and A are different things. Did you mean input current 20A? If so, why is output 0.35A? And where did 60W come from? How would anyone know the switching frequency with just that information?

Comment: Too many things don't make sense.  This thing will take 960 W in, but only produce 60 W out?  That would be 6% efficient.  Then how can the output be 200 V at 350 mA (70 W) when you say it is 60 W.  You're not ready yet for whatever it is you are trying to do.  Go back and learn some basics.  At your apparent level, you should just be buying power supplies, not trying to design them at this power.

Comment: Insufficient design specs, R,L,C for every component and wire, that includes DCR,RdsOn, ESR. Go pick a design from WebBench or elsewhere

Comment: Perhaps the OP does mean \$20\:\text{Ah}\$. If so, it's probably a battery application and the OP either doesn't understand how to phrase things in English or else doesn't understand some fundamentals of physics. If it is amp-hours and a rechargeable or replaceable battery situation, then this would be a system designed to operate for about half a day before needing to renew the power source. Which isn't unreasonable in some imaginable circumstances. The output spec of a peak compliance of \$350\:\text{mA}\$ is at least consistent with the prior two notes given.

Answer (score 2):

You choose the frequency, and that will help you decide on values for your capacitors and inductors.

It sounds like you need to learn a lot more about switching converters before attempting this.

Look at online calculators to help you see how things interact.  For instance:  [Texas Instrument's 'Power Designer'.](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator)